# Debugging f12 developer tools in ie11 using VirtualBox

Tags: internet-explorer, virtual-machine, virtualbox

So i'm testing my site in IE and older versions of IE allow me to open up `F12 developers tools` and debug my site however, on `IE11` I get the following error when I open my developer tools up : `Exception in window.onload: Error: An error has occurredJSPlugin.3005`

I had a look around and found this : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/imposible-use-f12-developer-tools-exception-in/09b4f305-e436-4615-a8a5-705b0bc85bbd?auth=1

however, once I try the download on `virtalBox` it errors and won't let me install.

Anyone come across this issue that can help?

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into this and concluded (like many) that KB3008923 is the one needed to fix this. But sadly if you search for 'KB3008923' you get only the 32 bit version of it. For 64 bit machines use the right link (note the last number in the URL). After applying the 64 bit version, i am now able to use F12 tools on Windows 7 64 bit. For the sake of completeness i am providing both URLs here

[32 bit link ending with the number 45134](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45134)

[64 bit link ending with the number 45154](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45154)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be great if the down voter explains the reason too!!